# how to write nhibernate code to get a particular in a particular row returned from the database

Tags: c#, nhibernate

Lets say my stored procedure is something like

```
create procedure mySp
As

    select a, b, c, d, e from aTable

End
```

I want to get the value of `d` for the last row. That is the only value that I am interested in. I don't want to map the result to a C# object or anything. Just need the value of `d` for the last row.

What should my nhibernate query look like?
Here is how I would start the call. But I can't get to the rest of it:

```
return unitOfWork.Session.CreateSQLQuery("exec mySP"). ??
```

Comment: It's just a business requirement Dave. I need to use an existing stored procedure that does some calculations. I have access to the stored procedure so I know the index of the column that I am interested in. Trying to find out the shortest way to get that through NHibernate.

Comment: I edited query in stored procedure "removed top 10" just to avoid any confusion. I need the last row. Not the 10th row.

Comment: To me, your request reads like this, "How do I do something in NHibernate, but not use NHibernate at all?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use Object-Relational Mapping tool but without objects and mapping. The most convenient way - don't do this, just use old-school `SqlCommand` for that.

if all you have is a hammer, everything looks like a nail

Answer (score 0):

If you have a requirement to get some value out of a stored procedure, but don't or won't map it to another object, then just expose a connection in your UnitOfWork interface.

Or simply add "int MySpecialDbCall()" method and call it a day.

It's "ugly" but I've had to do a similar thing.